# How to write matrix in c?

Tags: c, matrix, printf, scanf

I have a 5 to 4 matrix. I'm making 20 number entries. I want to write these number entries to the text file, but the numbers are not written.Here my codes;

```
int main()
{  
    int hw[5][4];
    int i, j;  
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "w");   

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
            printf("Enter value for HW[%d][%d]:", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &hw[i][j]);

            fprintf(fp,"%d\n",&hw[i][j]);

            if(hw[i][j]>=30)
            {
                printf("helloo");
            }     
        }
    }   
   fclose(fp);

    printf("HOMEWORKS:\n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
            printf("%d ", hw[i][j]);
            if(j==3){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove `&` from: `fprintf(fp,"%d\n",&hw[i][j]);`

Comment: I would guess you copy-pasted the `scanf` line and changed `scanf` to `fprintf`. Please be careful when copy-pasting code, especially if the end result will be something that's really very different from what you're copying (as in this case).

Comment: Opening a file named `input.txt` for writing is contradictory from a programmer's perspective, though not an error per se.

Comment: What compiler are you using? GCC should have issued a warning about the mismatched format/type. Always use `-gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: Please note that you don't need `if(j==3){ printf("\n"); }` there. Just add the newline *after* the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

As `usr` says you need to remove the `&` from the `fprintf(fp,"%d\n",&hw[i][j]);`.

This because `&` will return the location where `hw[i][j]` is stored and not the value it holds.

You might want to take a look at [pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The error is in fprintf call.

You need to remove the **"&"** before `hw[i][j]` in the *fprintf* call ( as in the printf() function) . The resulting code will be this:

```
int main()
{  
    int hw[5][4];
    int i, j;  
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "w");   

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
            printf("Enter value for HW[%d][%d]:", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &hw[i][j]);

            fprintf(fp,"%d\n",hw[i][j]);

            if(hw[i][j]>=30)
            {
                printf("helloo");
            }     
        }
    }   
   fclose(fp);

    printf("HOMEWORKS:\n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
            printf("%d ", hw[i][j]);
            if(j==3){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I attach you also an useful guide for fprintf function:

[fprintf() - tutorialpoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm)